# Updating page content using ReactJS and AJAX

Tags: json, ajax, node.js, reactjs

I'm new to react.js . I created a webpage with react.js which fetches data from json file (file is at server) and display it.

I want that changes in json file should reflect in webpage without reloading page so I used following code:

(this is not full code)

```
 getInitialState: function() {
    return {data: []};
  },
   componentDidMount: function() {
        this.loadFromServer();
        setInterval(this.loadFromServer, 2000);
      }
```

and loadFromServer():

```
loadFromServer: function() {
    $.ajax({
      url: this.props.url,
      dataType: 'json',
      cache: false,
      success: function(data) {
        this.setState({data: data});
      }.bind(this),
      error: function(xhr, status, err) {
        console.error(this.props.url, status, err.toString());
      }.bind(this)
    });
  }
```

It works well.

But problem I'm facing is that it keeps on fetching json file data in every 2 secs even if there is no change in data.

Please see this: [image]

Here file size is only 8.28 KB, but in future it will increase. I want a solution that it should fetch data from JSON file at server only when there is a change in data. I'm implementing server using Nodejs (express).

Comment: i think setInterval(this.loadFromServer, 2000); is the cause for service call for every 2 seconds

Comment: Yes I did this to continuously fetch file from server. But I want a condition to limit this fetching. I want it should fetch file only when there is some change in json file at server.

Comment: Then i think there is no way until server notifies the change to client by some way like socket.io. Else you can create a small service which continuous ping the server every 2 sec and depending on the response try calling the actual service instead calling it every time and repainting the client which is a heavy task.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once the ajax call is finished, the client (browser) has no way to know what goes on server side without asking the server.

There are many ways to avoid the systematic fetching of a huge json payload :

- ask for a json diff - cf https://www.npmjs.com/package/jiff for example but you will need to keep track of which version each client has
- ask if there is new data available before fetching the json payload - you will need to give an ID to the json payload to compare the client side ID with the server side ID ; or you could timestamp the json and use the timestamp as ID so the server would know that the client has stale data
- choose a realtime framework like socket.io so that the server will be able to inform the client that new data has arrived
- use a solution based on HTTP 304
- and probably many more

Comment: I searched about socket.io . I also found socketcluster.io, which one will be best for solving my issue. Any guess??

Answer (score 0):

You must use setTimeout

```
setTimeout(this.loadFromServer, 2000);
```

because setInterval will be called for every 2 seconds. but setTimeout will trigger after 2 seconds

**Edit :-** If you want to update the component for some data change on server, as @jerome suggested use socket.io and register callback in component

Comment: Using setTimeout the json would never update after the first retrieval which is not what the OP wants to to

Comment: @JeromeWAGNER: oh i did nt see that comment